# How do i find a value in an array in the most efficient way in that case?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

**NOTE: this algorithm should be done in the most efficient way that's a bad idea to have O(n^2)**

This is a two dimensional array, now notice it's hard to see that in first glance but there is a hidden pattern on that array.

[image]

this array is actually sorted take a look at that image below you may see the pattern now.

[image]

the goal here is to make a function that searches for a value in an array that follows the exact pattern like the array i've showed you in the image and you need to **return true** if the value was **found** and also **print** the column and row where the value **sits** in the array.
if value **wasn't found** **return false**

here is an example

here is the function signature

```
public static boolean search(int [][]mat,int num){
    //Code Here
}
```

let's say we are looking for the value `22` in that array(the same array in the image)

```
int [][]arr= {{1,3,7,9},{6,4,15,11},{36,50,21,22},{60,55,30,26}}
search(arr,22); //Returns true and also will be printed "row = 2 col = 3"

search(arr,86); //Returns false
```

Comment: is it always a `4*4` matrix?

Comment: Yes it's always 4*4 matrix.

Comment: Did you define the sort order yourself or was it mentioned in the problem statement? Also, trying to reduce a total of 16 comparisons won't give you a significant gain.

Comment: I assume this is just for educational purposes, as this wouldn't create any benefits in terms of optimization. In that case, I suggest you hard code at least parts of it. Do a binary search. You know where the mid lies, then do another binary search. Since there are 16 cells this will be `log(16)` = 4 comparisons at most.

Comment: For just 16 items, it will probably be the fastest to just search them all linearly, not using any fancy algorithm with lots of overhead (but better complexity). "*that's a bad idea to have O(n^2)*" - what does `n` denote there? And most importantly, how do you encode the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indices `i` and `j` into your matrix can be computed from a single linear index ranging from 0 through 15. This will allow you to do a normal binary search just translating each index from 1D to 2D.

```
private static int i(int index) {
    return iBit(index / 4) * 2 + iBit(index % 4);
}

private static int iBit(int part) {
    return (part / 2) ^ (part % 2);
}

private static int j(int index) {
    int temp = index / 2;
    return temp / 4 * 2 + temp % 2;
}
```

It’s a bit tricky. So let’s check that the methods work:

```
    for (int index = 0; index < 16; index++) {
        System.out.format("%2d -> %d %d%n", index, i(index), j(index));
    }
```

Output:

> ```
>  0 -> 0 0
>  1 -> 1 0
>  2 -> 1 1
>  3 -> 0 1
>  4 -> 2 0
>  5 -> 3 0
>  6 -> 3 1
>  7 -> 2 1
>  8 -> 2 2
>  9 -> 3 2
> 10 -> 3 3
> 11 -> 2 3
> 12 -> 0 2
> 13 -> 1 2
> 14 -> 1 3
> 15 -> 0 3
> ```

The numbers agree with the pattern in the question.

> **NOTE: this algorithm should be done in the most efficient way that's a bad idea to have O(n^2)**

It’s really nonsense. Big-O is defined based on the behaviour as the input size grows towards infinity. 16 does not grow towards infinty. Nor does 4. When the matrix size is constant, even a simple linear search will be O(1).

Comment: Though it is technically true that any solution is O(1), it makes sense to generalize this problem to any size.